# Meteor Android app doesn't display external images

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I have a meteor app with `App.accessRule("*")` (for testing purposes). The built iOS version has no problem accessing external images, while the android one can't.

I've tried various App.accessRule variations I've found as from the posts I've seen it's often linked to that. but to no avail.

Accessing the web app, from a browser on the phone works fine, the compiled version doesn't.

External paths vary from google images [ex](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-OsyrtJWPSKs/Vv9fy0pnS3I/AAAAAAAAckE/p30duBnRWSUgZez7GiKnubTxx9JwmcUAA/w1000-h1000-k/) to cloudinary public urls [ex](https://res.cloudinary.com/dnainlee3/image/upload/v1468318362/eyozpnxmatsw2pubikxw.png).

Any ideas?

Comment: need more information. Please specify any additional information, errors, logcat, etc. Also include what you've tried, the external image paths, etc.

Comment: I don't get any error when I emulate in chrome. How do I access logs on a device?

Comment: so it's when you use a different web browser outside of chrome on Android?

Comment: It's when I use the compliled and deployed version of the app (meteor built in browser?), the deployed web app in Chrome on the phone works fine.

Comment: Accessing the webapp with Firefox on a phone works fine as well, it really seem to be an Android build pb

Comment: did you add App.accessRule('http://*');

Comment: also inapp browser package: meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

Comment: do you want to force the Android OS's web browser or would prefer the built in cordova one?

Comment: No opinion? What's the point?

Comment: Do I need to change any code with the cordova in app browser?

Comment: you can use _system when calling the image url. var url="http://www.test.com/yourimage.png"; var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, _system, options);

Comment: should force the app to use external browser for OS, and bypass internal cordova one

Comment: Ok I'm trying that now

Comment: Ok so I tried to use InAppBrowser, this way images are accessible BUT before I could try to make it work everywhere, I rebuilt the android APK and redeployed it and the old way works... Maybe the App.accessRule gets built in cordova and wasn't passed properly through the hot code push?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'm keeping the InAppBrowser solution in my belt I'm sure it'll be usefull !